# Formatting PDF attachment in Google Apps Script (MailApp.sendEmail)

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script

I set up a script to convert an office contact list in Google Sheets to PDF and email it to a list every month as an attachment.  I'm trying to figure out how to format the PDF to be in landscape and remove gridlines and haven't had success.  I'm relatively new to scripting so I'm sure I'm missing something.  Here is my code.  I'd appreciate any advice.  Thanks!

```js
function EmailSpreadsheetAsPDF() {
  
 var file = DriveApp.getFileById('xxxxx_spreadsheet_key_xxxxx');
  
 var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-7", "MMMM yyyy");
  Logger.log(formattedDate);
  
 var email = "xxxxx@xxxxx.xxx";
  
 var subject = "Contact List - " + formattedDate;
  
 var body = "Attached is the current contact list for " + formattedDate + "." + "\n\nPlease email xxxxx@xxxxx.xxx with any corrections or updates.";
  
 MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
     name: 'xxxxx',
     attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You will however have to user UrlFetchApp for this purpose. As shown [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579)(read post#89), you can export the file as a PDF while setting gridline visibility to false by using the following command:

```
var pdfBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key="
               +docKey
               +"&exportFormat=pdf&gid="
               +printSheetIndex
               +"&gridlines=false&printtitle=false&size=A4&sheetnames=false&fzr=true&portrait="
               +portraitInd
               +"&fitw=true"
               , requestData).getBlob().setName(docName);
```

Read the provided link for more detailed information.